# select only one checkbox in gridview and edit that checked row

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

i have a gridview and which has one column as the asp checkbox control and i want the user can check one check box and click on the edit button to edit that perticular row

my code for this is

```
                 <asp:GridView runat="server" CssClass="width" ID="gvGrades" AutoGenerateColumns="false" ShowHeader="true" OnRowCancelingEdit="gvGrades_RowCancelingEdit"                            OnRowCommand="gvGrades_RowCommand" OnRowDataBound="gvGrades_RowDataBound" OnRowEditing="gvGrades_RowEditing"                               OnRowUpdated="gvGrades_RowUpdated" OnRowUpdating="gvGrades_RowUpdating" OnRowDeleting="gvGrades_RowDeleting">
                            <Columns>
                                <asp:TemplateField>
                                    <HeaderTemplate>
                                        Select

                                    </HeaderTemplate>
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkSelect" class="asp" runat="server"  />

                                        <asp:Label ID="lblId" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("id") %>' Visible="false"></asp:Label>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                <asp:TemplateField>
                                    <HeaderTemplate>
                                        Grade Name
                                    </HeaderTemplate>
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("grade_name") %>'></asp:Label>
                                    </ItemTemplate>

                                 </asp:TemplateField>
                                <asp:TemplateField>
                                    <HeaderTemplate>
                                        Organization Name
                                    </HeaderTemplate>
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:Label ID="lblOrganizationName" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("organization_name") %>'></asp:Label>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                <asp:TemplateField>
                                    <HeaderTemplate>
                                        Minimum Basic Salary
                                    </HeaderTemplate>
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:Label ID="lblSalary" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("min_basic_salary") %>'></asp:Label>
                                    </ItemTemplate>

                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                <asp:TemplateField>
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="lnkDelete" CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete"></asp:LinkButton>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                <asp:TemplateField>
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="lnkEdit" CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit"></asp:LinkButton>
                                    </ItemTemplate>

                                </asp:TemplateField>
                            </Columns>
                        </asp:GridView>
                    </fieldset>
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
            <asp:Button Text="Add" Width="70px" ID="btnAdd" runat="server" OnClick="btnAdd_Click" />&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <asp:Button Text="Edit" ID="btnEdit" Width="70px" runat="server" OnClick="btnEdit_Click"
                />
```

Please provide code for edit button click also

thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far?  We will help you fix it if you have put in some effort yourself.  We aren't here to do your work for you.

Comment: i have a post back code but i want to do it through jquery or javascript

Answer (score 1):

use can use [GridView.SelectedIndexChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.selectedindexchanged.aspx)  Event.

you might do something like this

```
<asp:TemplateField >
            <ItemTemplate>     
                <asp:CheckBox ID="chb1" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField>
```

and you can set the edit fied `enable=false` and in the postback you can set `enable=true`

```
protected void GVSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
            var check = (CheckBox) e.Row.FindControl("chb1");
            if(check != null)
            {
                    // do something
            }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below steps for enable edit button without postback [using javascript]

1. Register OnRowDataBound event of Gridview.
2. Find the checkbox and Edit button using the itemindex [in Onrowbound event]
3. After finding checkbox, register javascript function onchange event with parameter [of Edit button Id]
4. Then you will get the Edit button in javascript
5. Put the javascript enable code.

Let me know if you have any problem or query.